# Do the tetramminecopper(II) and hexathiocyanatoferrate(III) complexes obey the 18-electron rule?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

Can anyone tell me whether $\ce{[Cu(NH3)4]^2+}$ and $\ce{[Fe(SCN)6]^3-}$ obey the 18-electron rule, and if not, why? I found $\ce{[Cu(NH3)4]^2+}$ and  $\ce{[Fe(SCN)6]^3-}$ have 17 electrons, was I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: This is an unsatisfactory answer so I will just comment: there is absolutely no reason why those compounds should obey the 18e rule.

Comment: @orthocresol if there is no reason,why we need 18-electron rule

Comment: Because there are other compounds that do obey it.

Comment: @orthocresol such as?

Comment: Try Google or Wikipedia. They're pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found $\ce{[Cu(NH3)4]^2+}$ and $\ce{[Fe(SCN)6]^3-}$ have 17 electrons, was I wrong?

You are correct for the iron(III) complex, which has an uneven electron count and is a $\mathrm{d^5}$ system. You are almost correct for copper(II), but that complex is actually $\ce{[Cu(NH3)4(H2O)2]^2+}$ where the two aqua-ligands are further away from the metal centre. In any case, it is a $\mathrm{d^9}$ system and has 21 electrons.

No system in which the central metal has an uneven electron number can fulfill the 18-electron rule unless there are radical ligands around which happens rather rarely.

So what is the benefit of the rule? Well, complexes involving 18 electrons — that would be ten d-electrons, two s-electrons and six p-electrons in extremely simplified terms — are often noted to be more stable than others with respect to decomposition. So iron forms a pentacarbonyliron(0) compound ($\mathrm{d^8}$) with ten electrons coming from the five carbon monoxide ligands. This compound is rather stable with respect to oxidation and decomposition while a hexacarbonyliron(0) or a tetracarbonyliron(0) are not. But you should take this 18-electron rule with a much larger grain of salt then the octet rule for main group elements.

Answer (score 0):

Only for some complexing agents do we typically expect the 18-electron rule to hold.  The best candidates are very "soft-base" ligands with strong pi-electron interactions, like CO.  Ammonia and thiocyanate do not do this.